method getCollection() from Astro doesn't sync the contents from Cloudinary library correctly
I have a simple Astro project and I'm using the Cloudinary integration to sync a folder from my Cloudinary library to mi project.
---
import Carousel from "@components/Carousel.astro";
import { CldImage } from "astro-cloudinary";
import { getCollection } from "astro:content";
const images = await getCollection("images");

console.log("Gallery", images);
---

<section class="web__version">
    <ul>
        {
            images.map((elem) => {
                return (
                    <li>
                        <CldImage
                            id="image-events"
                            src={elem.data.public_id}
                            width={elem.data.width}
                            height={elem.data.height}
                            alt="ok"
                        />
                    </li>
                );
            })
        }
    </ul>

</section>

I retrieve all the images, and it's works fine, but when I delete some images, and I restart the project, all the images seems to be keeping in memory and stills appearing in my Gallery, even when the url in the src of the images is broken.
I have my collection configuration like this:
import { cldAssetsLoader } from 'astro-cloudinary/loaders';
import { defineCollection } from 'astro:content';

export const collections = {
    images: defineCollection({
      loader: cldAssetsLoader({
        folder: 'salem-uploads'
      })
    })
  }

I'm uncertain about how to retrieve all images correctly. I've conducted some tests, and it seems that if I upload a new photo and delete others, the deleted images remain in my gallery while the new ones also appear.
If I console the images object, appears in console all the images and the urls seems to be broken, except for the photos that actually exists in my Cloudinary library.

Could you try to purge the local browser cache to check if the assets rendered are coming from CDN. Additionally, when you delete the assets directly from the Cloudinary Media Library console, the cached images in the CDN will also be invalidated. And if you delete/destroy them through the SDK, you will need to use the parameter invalidate=true - see https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_optional_parameters
